# Is there something substantial behind this solution technique?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation, systems-of-equations, triangles

In [this video](https://youtu.be/5fYaiZYcZuo?t=479), the two variable equation $(1 - \alpha - \frac{\gamma}{2})\vec A + (\frac{\alpha}{2} - \frac{\gamma}{2})\vec B + (-1 + \frac{\alpha}{2} + \gamma)\vec C = \vec 0$ is solved by introducing four additional variables, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\beta$.  This seems like overkill, and I'm confused about why it even helps.  The idea is that each coefficient is proportional with constant $\beta$ to $a$, $b$, $c$, respectively, but this move feels like renaming the coefficient expressions without adding new information.

It is noted in the video that if we were to make the false assumption that each coefficient must equal $0$ in order for the entire linear combination to equal $0$, then we would have three equations and two variables, but would get "lucky" and find the solution $(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{3})$, which is in fact the answer that needs to be proven.

Is this "luckiness" of finding a solution to the overdetermined system secretly the reason that an answer is obtainable by the professor's ultimate solution method, or does introducing $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\beta$ actually add something needed for the proof?

EDIT (requested image):
[image: https://i.imgur.com/vCECyrR.png]

Comment: Questions on SE network should, in general, be self-contained.  Please improve this question by 1. typing some relevant equations 2. (optional, but suggested) provide a picture of the geometric figure on the left-hand-side of the board shown in the video.

Comment: Done, I'll still leave the link in case it's helpful.

Comment: I hope I read your question correctly.  The points are given, and we have to solve for the scalars in greek letter.

Comment: I didn't click into the video, but I guess that $a,b,c$ represent the sides of the triangle $ABC$.  It's reasonable to do so since the vector $\vec{A}$ involves the origin, which is *irrelevant* to the probem.  Thus, it's reasonable to think of $\vec{A} - \vec{B}$ to eliminate the origin.